# convert comment (list) to dataframe ,pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have big list of names , I want to keep it in my interpreter so I would like not use csv files.
The only way how i can store it in my interpreter as variable using 'copy -paste' from my original file is `comment`

so my input looks like this :

```
temp='''A,B,C
        adam,dorothy,ben
        luis,cristy,hoover'''
```

my goal is to convert this 'comment' inside my interpreter to dataframe
i tried to 
`df=pd.DataFrame([temp])` and also to series using in comment only one column but without success, any idea? 
my read data have hundreds of lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
from io import StringIO

temp=u'''A,B,C
        adam,dorothy,ben
        luis,cristy,hoover'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp))
print (df)
              A        B       C
0          adam  dorothy     ben
1          luis   cristy  hoover
```

Comment: working, thank you, i had to add `temp=u''' data'''`
because i am usiung python 2.7